# Versioning Report Projects with Team foundation server

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2005

When i try to use Team Foundation Server to version a report project with visual 2005 like these

[image]

But when I try to save it, the following errors appears

[image]

Do you have any idea how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your workspace first. The local folder is not mapped to a source control folder in TFS yet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx